# checkbox set to check if in DB value is 1 and update db on click on it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have working datatable. I need to set checkbox checked in modal if in DB my value is 1 and unchecked if value is 0. Also I need to make it working on click. If i uncheck i need to update value in my db to 0. Here is my code of table and workign datatable.

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-38304687-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
  
  //JS TO FILL AND BUTTONS
  
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // ATW
    if ( top.location.href != location.href ) top.location.href = location.href;

    // Initialize datatable
    $('#example').dataTable({
     "aProcessing": true,
     "aServerSide": true,
     "ajax": "datatable.php?ajax"
    });

    // Save edited row
    $("#edit-form").on("submit", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $.post("datatable.php?edit=" + $('#edit-id').val(), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
      var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
      var tr = $('a[data-id="row-' + $('#edit-id').val() + '"]').parent().parent();
      $('td:eq(1)', tr).html(obj.AD);
      $('td:eq(2)', tr).html(obj.SOYAD);
      $('td:eq(3)', tr).html(obj.ATAADI);
      $('td:eq(4)', tr).html(obj.SHEXSINOM);
      $('td:eq(5)', tr).html(obj.SHIRKETNOM);
      $('td:eq(6)', tr).html(obj.WHATSAPPNOM);
      $('td:eq(7)', tr).html(obj.TABELKOD);
      $('td:eq(8)', tr).html(obj.BAL);
      $('td:eq(9)', tr).html(obj.VOEN);
      $('td:eq(10)', tr).html(obj.SHEXSIYAT);
      $('td:eq(11)', tr).html(obj.PRAVA);
      $('td:eq(12)', tr).html(obj.MAHKARAYIS);
      $('td:eq(13)', tr).html(obj.XIDMETMUQAV);
      $('td:eq(14)', tr).html(obj.FOURPIC);
      $('td:eq(15)', tr).html(obj.TELIMAT);
      $('#edit-modal').modal('hide');
     }).fail(function() { alert('Unable to save data, please try again later.'); });
    });

    // Add new row
    $("#add-form").on("submit", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $.post("datatable.php?add", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
      var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
      $('#example tbody tr:last').after('<tr role="row"><td class="sorting_1">' + obj.id + '</td><td>' + obj.AD + '</td><td>' + obj.SOYAD + '</td><td>' + obj.ATAADI + '</td><td>' + obj.ISHSTARTTIME + '</td><td>' + obj.SHEXSINOM + '</td><td>' + obj.SHIRKETNOM + '</td><td>' + obj.WHATSAPPNOM + '</td><td>' + obj.TABELKOD + '</td><td>' + obj.BAL + '</td><td>' + obj.VOEN ==1 + '</td><td>' + obj.SHEXSIYAT + '</td><td>' + obj.PRAVA + '</td><td>' + obj.MAHKARAYIS + '</td><td>' + obj.XIDMETMUQAV + '</td><td>' + obj.FOURPIC + '</td><td>' + obj.TELIMAT + '</td><td><a data-id="row-' + obj.id + '" href="javascript:editRow(' + obj.id + ');" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">edit</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:removeRow(' + obj.id + ');" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">remove</a></td></tr>');
      $('#add-modal').modal('hide');
     }).fail(function() { alert('Unable to save data, please try again later.'); });
    });

   });
            
   // Edit row
   function editRow(id) {
    if ( 'undefined' != typeof id ) {
     $.getJSON('datatable.php?edit=' + id, function(obj) {
      $('#edit-id').val(obj.id);
      $('#firstname').val(obj.AD);
      $('#SOYAD').val(obj.SOYAD);
      $('#ATAADI').val(obj.ATAADI);
      $('#SHEXSINOM').val(obj.SHEXSINOM);
      $('#SHIRKETNOM').val(obj.SHIRKETNOM);
      $('#WHATSAPPNOM').val(obj.WHATSAPPNOM);
      $('#TABELKOD').val(obj.TABELKOD);
      $('#BAL').val(obj.BAL);
      $('#VOEN').val(obj.VOEN);
      $('#SHEXSIYAT').val(obj.SHEXSIYAT);
      $('#PRAVA').val(obj.PRAVA);
      $('#MAHKARAYIS').val(obj.MAHKARAYIS);
      $('#XIDMETMUQAV').val(obj.XIDMETMUQAV);
      $('#FOURPIC').val(obj.FOURPIC);
      $('#TELIMAT').val(obj.TELIMAT);
      $('#edit-modal').modal('show')
     }).fail(function() { alert('Unable to fetch data, please try again later.') });
    } else alert('Unknown row id.');

   }

   // Remove row
   function removeRow(id) {
    if ( 'undefined' != typeof id ) {
     $.get('datatable.php?remove=' + id, function() {
      $('a[data-id="row-' + id + '"]').parent().parent().remove();
     }).fail(function() { alert('Unable to fetch data, please try again later.') });
    } else alert('Unknown row id.');
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>  
    
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<?php

//For more Info: Please visit: http://www.discussdesk.com/bootstrap-datatable-with-add-edit-remove-option-in-php-mysql-ajax.htm

 // VARIABLES
 $aColumns = array('id', 'AD', 'SOYAD', 'ATAADI', 'SHEXSINOM', 'SHIRKETNOM', 'WHATSAPPNOM', 'TABELKOD');
 $sIndexColumn = "id";
 $sTable = "";
 $gaSql['user'] = "";
 $gaSql['password'] = "";
 $gaSql['db'] = "";
 $gaSql['server'] = "";


 // DATABASE CONNECTION
 function dbinit(&$gaSql) {
  // ERROR HANDLING
  function fatal_error($sErrorMessage = '') {
   header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error');
   die($sErrorMessage);
  }

  // MYSQL CONNECT
  if ( !$gaSql['link'] = @mysql_connect($gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']) ) {
   fatal_error('Could not open connection to server');
  }

  // MYSQL DATABASE SELECT
  if ( !mysql_select_db($gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link']) ) {
   fatal_error('Could not select database');
  }
 }

 // AJAX EDIT FROM JQUERY
 if ( isset($_GET['edit']) && 0 < intval($_GET['edit']) ) {
  dbinit($gaSql);

  // SAVE DATA
  if ( isset($_POST) ) {
   $p = $_POST;
   foreach ( $p as &$val ) $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
   if ( !empty($p['firstname']) && !empty($p['SOYAD']) && !empty($p['ATAADI']) )
    @mysql_query(" UPDATE $sTable SET AD = '" . $p['firstname'] . "', SOYAD = '" . $p['SOYAD'] . "', ATAADI = '" . $p['ATAADI'] . "', SHEXSINOM = '" . $p['SHEXSINOM'] . "', SHIRKETNOM  = '" . $p['SHIRKETNOM '] . "', WHATSAPPNOM = '" . $p['WHATSAPPNOM'] . "', TABELKOD = '" . $p['TABELKOD'] . "', BAL = '" . $p['BAL'] . "', VOEN = '" . $p['VOEN'] . "', BAL = '" . $p['BAL'] . "', SHEXSIYAT = '" . $p['SHEXSIYAT'] . "', PRAVA = '" . $p['PRAVA'] . "', MAHKARAYIS = '" . $p['MAHKARAYIS'] . "', XIDMETMUQAV = '" . $p['XIDMETMUQAV'] . "', FOURPIC = '" . $p['FOURPIC'] . "', TELIMAT = '" . $p['TELIMAT'] . "' WHERE id = " . intval($_GET['edit']));
  }

  // GET DATA
  $query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM $sTable WHERE $sIndexColumn = " . intval($_GET['edit']), $gaSql['link']);

  die(json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($query)));
 }

 // AJAX ADD FROM JQUERY
 if ( isset($_GET['add']) && isset($_POST) ) {
  dbinit($gaSql);

  $p = $_POST;
  foreach ( $p as &$val ) $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
  if ( !empty($p['firstname']) && !empty($p['SOYAD']) && !empty($p['ATAADI']) ) {
   @mysql_query(" INSERT INTO $sTable (AD, SOYAD, ATAADI) VALUES ('" . $p['firstname'] . "', '" . $p['SOYAD'] . "', '" . $p['ATAADI'] . "')");
   $id = mysql_insert_id();
   $query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM $sTable WHERE $sIndexColumn = " . $id, $gaSql['link']);
   die(json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($query)));
  }
 }

 // AJAX REMOVE FROM JQUERY
 if ( isset($_GET['remove']) && 0 < intval($_GET['remove']) ) {
  dbinit($gaSql);

  // REMOVE DATA
  @mysql_query(" DELETE FROM $sTable WHERE id = " . intval($_GET['remove']));
 }


 // AJAX FROM JQUERY
 if ( isset($_GET['ajax']) ) {
  dbinit($gaSql);

  // QUERY LIMIT
  $sLimit = "";
  if ( isset($_GET['iDisplayStart']) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' ) {
   $sLimit = "LIMIT " . intval($_GET['iDisplayStart']) . ", " . intval($_GET['iDisplayLength']);
  }

  // QUERY ORDER
  $sOrder = "";
  if ( isset($_GET['iSortCol_0']) ) {
   $sOrder = "ORDER BY ";
   for ( $i = 0; $i < intval($_GET['iSortingCols']); $i++ ) {
    if ( $_GET['bSortable_' . intval($_GET['iSortCol_' . $i])] == "true" ) {
     $sOrder .= $aColumns[intval($_GET['iSortCol_' . $i])] . " " . ( $_GET['sSortDir_' . $i] === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc' ) . ", ";
    }
   }
   $sOrder = substr_replace($sOrder, "", -2);
   if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" ) $sOrder = "";
  }

  // QUERY SEARCH
  $sWhere = "";
  if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" ) {
   $sWhere = "WHERE (";
   for ( $i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++ ) {
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_' . $i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_' . $i] == "true" ) {
     $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch']) . "%' OR ";
    }
   }
   $sWhere = substr_replace($sWhere, "", -3);
   $sWhere .= ')';
  }

  // BUILD QUERY
  for ( $i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++ ) {
   if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_' . $i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_' . $i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_' . $i] != '' ) {
    if ( $sWhere == "" ) $sWhere = "WHERE ";
    else $sWhere .= " AND ";
    $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_' . $i]) . "%' ";
   }
  }

  // FETCH
  $sQuery = " SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS " . str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns)) . " FROM $sTable $sWhere $sOrder $sLimit ";
  $rResult = mysql_query($sQuery, $gaSql['link']) or fatal_error('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno());
  $sQuery = " SELECT FOUND_ROWS() ";
  $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query($sQuery, $gaSql['link']) or fatal_error('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno());
  $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
  $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];
  $sQuery = " SELECT COUNT(" . $sIndexColumn . ") FROM $sTable ";
  $rResultTotal = mysql_query($sQuery, $gaSql['link']) or fatal_error('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno());
  $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
  $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
  while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array($rResult) ) {
   $row = array();
   for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count($aColumns); $i++ ) {
    if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" ) $row[] = ( $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] == "0" ) ? '-' : $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
    else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' ) $row[] = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
   }
   $output['aaData'][] = array_merge($row, array('<a data-id="row-' . $row[0] . '" href="javascript:editRow(' . $row[0] . ');" class="btn btn-md btn-success">edit</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:removeRow(' . $row[0] . ');" class="btn btn-default btn-md" style="background-color: #c83a2a;border-color: #b33426; color: #ffffff;">remove</a>'));
  }

  // RETURN IN JSON
  die(json_encode($output));
 }

?>
<!------------------------ code of table with modal---------------- -->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <button type="button" style="padding:10px; margin:0 50px 15px 0;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-modal"><b>Add More Rows</b></button>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 marginT20">

  <div class="table-responsive demo-x content">
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th><p>&#8470;</p></th>
     <th>AD</th>
     <th>Soyad</th>
     <th>Ata Adi</th>
     <th>Shexsi nomre</th>
     <th>Shirket nomre</th>
     <th>WhatsApp nomre</th>
     <th>Tabel nomre</th>
      <!--<th>Ishe Qabul</th>-->
     
     <th style="background-image: none">Edit</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="edit-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit-modal-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <form class="form-horizontal" id="edit-form">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="edit-modal-label">Edit selected row</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <input type="hidden" id="edit-id" value="" class="hidden">
            <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">AD</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="SOYAD" class="col-sm-2 control-label">SOYAD</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SOYAD" name="SOYAD" placeholder="E-mail address" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="ATAADI" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ATA ADI</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ATAADI" name="ATAADI" placeholder="ATA ADI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="SHEXSINOM" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Shexsi Nomre</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SHEXSINOM" name="SHEXSINOM" placeholder="SHEXSI NOMRESI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="SHIRKETNOM" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Shirket Nomresi</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SHIRKETNOM" name="SHIRKETNOM" placeholder="SHIRKET NOMRESI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="WHATSAPPNOM" class="col-sm-2 control-label">WHATSAPP NOMRE</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="WHATSAPPNOM" name="WHATSAPPNOM" placeholder="WHATSAPP NOMRE" required>
          </div>
        </div> <div class="form-group">
          <label for="TABELKOD" class="col-sm-2 control-label">TABEL KODU</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TABELKOD" name="TABELKOD" placeholder="TABEL KODU" required>
          </div>
        </div> <div class="form-group">
          <label for="BAL" class="col-sm-2 control-label">BAL</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="BAL" name="BAL" placeholder="BAL" required>
          </div>
        </div> <div class="form-group">
          <label for="VOEN" class="col-sm-2 control-label">VOEN</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="VOEN" name="VOEN" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div> <div class="form-group">
          <label for="SHEXSIYAT" class="col-sm-2 control-label">SHEXSIYAT</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="SHEXSIYAT" name="SHEXSIYAT" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div> <div class="form-group">
          <label for="PRAVA" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PRAVA</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="PRAVA" name="PRAVA" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="MAHKARAYIS" class="col-sm-2 control-label">MAHKARAYIS</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="MAHKARAYIS" name="MAHKARAYIS" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="XIDMETMUQAV" class="col-sm-2 control-label">XIDMETMUQAV</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="XIDMETMUQAV" name="XIDMETMUQAV" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="FOURPIC" class="col-sm-2 control-label">FOURPIC</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="FOURPIC" name="FOURPIC" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="TELIMAT" class="col-sm-2 control-label">TELIMAT</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" id="TELIMAT" name="TELIMAT"  required>
          </div>
        </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>
         </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="add-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add-modal-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <form class="form-horizontal" id="add-form">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="add-modal-label">Add new row</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">AD</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="SOYAD" class="col-sm-2 control-label">SOYAD</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-SOYAD" name="SOYAD" placeholder="E-mail address" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="ATAADI" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ATA ADI</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-ATAADI" name="ATAADI" placeholder="ATA ADI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="SHEXSINOM" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Shexsi Nomre</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-SHEXSINOM" name="SHEXSINOM" placeholder="SHEXSI NOMRESI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="SHIRKETNOM" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Shirket Nomresi</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-SHIRKETNOM" name="SHIRKETNOM" placeholder="SHIRKET NOMRESI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="WHATSAPPNOM" class="col-sm-2 control-label">WHATSAPP NOMRE</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-WHATSAPPNOM" name="WHATSAPPNOM" placeholder="WHATSAPP NOMRE" required>
          </div>
        </div> <div class="form-group">
          <label for="TABELKOD" class="col-sm-2 control-label">TABEL KODU</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-TABELKOD" name="TABELKOD" placeholder="TABEL KODU" required>
          </div>
        </div> <div class="form-group">
          <label for="BAL" class="col-sm-2 control-label">BAL</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-BAL" name="BAL" placeholder="BAL" required>
          </div>
        </div> <div class="form-group">
          <label for="VOEN" class="col-sm-2 control-label">VOEN</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="add-VOEN" name="VOEN" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div> <div class="form-group">
          <label for="SHEXSIYAT" class="col-sm-2 control-label">SHEXSIYAT</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="add-SHEXSIYAT" name="SHEXSIYAT" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div> <div class="form-group">
          <label for="PRAVA" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PRAVA</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="add-PRAVA" name="PRAVA" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="MAHKARAYIS" class="col-sm-2 control-label">MAHKARAYIS</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="add-MAHKARAYIS" name="MAHKARAYIS" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="XIDMETMUQAV" class="col-sm-2 control-label">XIDMETMUQAV</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="add-XIDMETMUQAV" name="XIDMETMUQAV" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="FOURPIC" class="col-sm-2 control-label">FOURPIC</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="add-FOURPIC" name="FOURPIC" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="TELIMAT" class="col-sm-2 control-label">TELIMAT</label>
       
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="add-TELIMAT" name="TELIMAT" placeholder="ATAADI" required>
          </div>
        </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>
         </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: And the actual question is?

Comment: I Have column 'TELIMAT' in DB and it is value is 1. In modal I  added checkbox input and want to connect it to DB. It should show on load "checked if value in db is 1" or "unchecked if in db value is 0". Also need to make it work onclick(should do update in DB "if checked should update clolumn to 1" or "if set uncheck should update column value to 0"